# How to pass a pointer to typedef function as parameter?

Tags: c, pointers, arduino, typedef

I am working to improve how a reaction is triggered inside PJON. It is a communication bus system for Arduino I am writing in c: https://github.com/gioblu/PJON

I have some trouble to define a pointer to a new type of function (typedef) that receives an int (length) and a pointer to an array of bytes ( *payload ):

In the .h file I declare the receiver type function:

```
typedef void (* receiver)(uint8_t length, uint8_t *payload);
```

The PJON class contains also:

```
receiver _receiver;
```

A setter will let the user set the function will be called automatically:

```
void PJON::set_receiver(receiver *r) {
  _receiver = r;
}
```

The user will have only to declare the function:

```
receiver led_blink(uint8_t length, uint8_t *payload) {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(30);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  Serial.println("SUCCESS");
};
```

and pass it to the setter:

```
network.set_receiver(led_blink);
```

When the system receives a message:

```
this->_receiver(data[1] - 4, data + 2);
```

Calls the function passing the actual parameters.

This is the error message I receive from the compiler:

```
PJON.ino: In function 'void setup()':
PJON.ino:14:33: error: no matching function for call to 'PJON::set_receiver(void (* (&)(uint8_t, uint8_t*))(uint8_t, uint8_t*))'
PJON.ino:14:33: note: candidate is:
In file included from PJON.ino:1:0:
C:\Users\gio\Desktop\Arduino Software\arduino-1.6.0\libraries\PJON/PJON.h:115:10: note: void PJON::set_receiver(void (**)(uint8_t, uint8_t*))
     void set_receiver(receiver *r);
          ^
C:\Users\gio\Desktop\Arduino Software\arduino-1.6.0\libraries\PJON/PJON.h:115:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void (*(uint8_t, uint8_t*))(uint8_t, uint8_t*) {aka void (*(unsigned char, unsigned char*))(unsigned char, unsigned char*)}' to 'void (**)(uint8_t, uint8_t*) {aka void (**)(unsigned char, unsigned char*)}'
```

I can't understand where is the mistake!!

Comment: This is not C ! And if that is Arduino, it is also not C++

Comment: Member function pointers don't fit for that callback. You need to make the function static.

Comment: Thank you both for the fast answer.Why is not c?? And, wich function should be static???

I know taht Wiring is not C and C++ but this is code from a library I am writing, obviously contains some of Wiring if you include it, but I think can be considered C

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void (* receiver)(uint8_t length, uint8_t *payload);
```

this defines the identifier `receiver` to be the type of *a pointer* to a function with the given signature (note the asterisk in the typedef). So

```
void PJON::set_receiver(receiver *r) {
    _receiver = r;
}
```

would actually expect a *pointer to a pointer to a function*. (leave out the asterisk here and it should express what you initially meant)

That's all I can say for sure as far as this is compatible with C and/or C++ ... arduino has its own (somewhat similar) language, as pointed out in the comments already -- it's still a different language.

Comment: Doing what you proposed I receive this error message:










In function 'void setup()':
 error: invalid conversion from 'void (* (*)(uint8_t, uint8_t*))(uint8_t, uint8_t*) {aka void (* (*)(unsigned char, unsigned char*))(unsigned char, unsigned char*)}' to 'receiver {aka void (*)(unsigned char, unsigned char*)}' [-fpermissive]
In file included from PJON_reborn_rx.ino:1:0:
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void PJON::set_receiver(receiver)' [-fpermissive]
     void set_receiver(receiver r);

Comment: are you sure the asterisk just before `payload` is there in your original `typedef` line? the error message suggests `receiver` to be defined like `typedef void (* receiver)(uint8_t length, uint8_t payload);` ... but maybe I also missed something here.

Comment: Yes the asterisk is there as you say, but now I am thinking, maybe the problem is how I pass the parameter inside the library:
    this->_receiver(data[1] - 4, data + 2);
data is an array of uint8_t, maybe i should pass it as a pointer? 
    this->receiver(data[1] - 4, *data + 2);

Comment: Hmmm ... if this is really C++ code (not this special arduino language) ... could you put a complete compilable example somewhere? I'd like to try it out myself ...

Comment: Here is a link to the actual code:
www.gioblu.com/GiO/PJON.zip

Comment: dammit, this doesn't lead anywhere: *includes/digitalWriteFast.h:5:24: fatal error: WProgram.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden* -- looks like some special framework is needed to compile this. I'll just have a look at the code, maybe I find something ....

Comment: Ok, still stepping in the dark ... these `pde` files in `examples` seem to be code in this special *arduino language*, right? still I don't see any call to your `set_receiver()` there ... where is it called? maybe the problem is where your actual callback-function is defined?

Comment: Ciao Felix you are right I forgot to pass you the actual code I was triyng with this library:
  network.set_receiver(led_blink);

receiver led_blink(uint8_t length, uint8_t *payload) {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(30);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  Serial.println("SUCCESS");
};

Comment: Well ... buona sera ... haha ... still something is missing to this puzzle. *Somewhere* there is a type conflict. Btw, this is really a drawback of a custom language like arduino is using, you won't find many experts (I didn't use it before). But I *guess* now the definition of `led_blink` is wrong here

Comment: following standard C / C++, it should look like this: `static void led_blink(uint8_t length, uint8_t *payload) { ... /* your implementing code */ ... }`

Comment: WHOO HOOO it works!! 
But why I should declare the functions as a static void and not as receiver type?? I miss something here

Comment: The `static` isn't important, but what IS important is that you need to declare the function the way your typedef is declared. if you declare it `receiver`, that would mean your function should return a function pointer compatible with your `receiver` type ... I hope that's clear enough?

Comment: To clarify a bit more ... the *function* is your *object* pointed to. With your original syntax, you declared a function returning a pointer to a function (because this is what your `typedef` declares). Instead you want a function returning `void` and taking two arguments of types `uint8_t` and `uint8_t *`. A pointer to THIS function would exactly match your `typedef`. Well then, buona notte to bella italia -- if you found my original answer helpful, please accept it (if not, still happy to help!).

Comment: Oh and as a final thought ... I'd be in favour of resurrecting the [tag:c] tag here, because, although arduino has its own incompatible language, the basic problem was well in the scope of [tag:c] :)